# Google App Engine Handler not displaying content

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications

Hi I'm trying to get my Google App Engine application running on local host but I'm getting issues when I try to run it.

This is the code I'm tryng to run:

```
# helloworld.py    

import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        #"Test" text is not displayed
        self.response.write("Test")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
debug=True)

#This line prints the content
print "This works fine"
```

When I run the dev server on localhost I get Code 200 as response but the handler doesn't seems to be executed properly.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, just make sure your in your `app.yaml` you have the handlers correct. It should look something like this:

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: helloworld.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

If you haven't done it yet, you should also complete the [Getting Started tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/).

Comment: I'm following the udacity course. By default GAE uses self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html' so it should display the content. Also the print statement was just a test.

Comment: @Nucklear That's strange then.. can you also provide the app.yaml that you are using?

Comment: I made it work adding the following code: def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

But in the udacity example they are not ussing that sentence...

Comment: @Nucklear I updated my answer.. check if you have the handlers like this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue. Using webapp2 library I have to add the folowing code to the *.yaml file:

```
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```